# Apache ProxyPassReverse fallback when host is down

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I have been unable to find any documentation to conclusively confirm or deny this apparent `mod_proxy` behaviour.

We have a web reverse proxy with multiple ProxyPassReverse definitions, similar to this:

```
ProxyPass        /foo http://fooserver/
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://fooserver/
ProxyPass        /    http://barserver/
ProxyPassReverse /    http://barserver/
```

As expected, requests for URLs under `/foo` go to `fooserver`, and all other requests get sent to `barserver`.

Recently, `fooserver` was shut down for other reasons.  Users noticed that - sometimes - requests for `/foo/xxx` were incorrectly being routed to `barserver` which responded with a 404 (we know it was `barserver` responding because it runs a different webserver software).

My question is this - is it deliberate that `ProxyPassReverse` will fall back to a lower-priority route if the destination server is down, and if so, under what conditions does this fallback happen?  I know that you can use `mod_balancer` if you want it to happen.  I'm more interested in why it is happening this time when I had not expected it to, and any pointers to relevant documentation.

Comment: No.It will not route the request to the second node Even I am not ablet to replicate the same behavior.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same behavior with a similar setup with apache httpd 2.4.46, no clue how to disable that.